# get IP address of java client in java server

Tags: java, ip

I need to check the client IP that connected to my java server with the IP list.

I used

```
Sock.getRemoteSocketAddress().equals(ip).
```

But getRemoteSocketAddress() gives 192.168.1.81:1115 but I need to get only the IP I.e 192.168.1.81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [`InetSocketAddress.getAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#getAddress%28%29) like

```
((InetSocketAddress) Sock.getRemoteSocketAddress()).getAddress()
```

Alternatively, you could use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) like

```
Sock.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString().split(":")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`req.getRemoteAddr()` is the method

if you have servlet then

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
 throws IOException {

        // Get client's IP address
        String ipAddress = req.getRemoteAddr(); // ip

        // Get client's hostname
        String hostname = req.getRemoteHost(); // hostname
    }
```

#

```
import java.net.*;


public class IP {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("www.xxx.com"));
    }
}
```

Comment: import java.net.*;


public class IP {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("www.xxx.com"));
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

servletRequest.getRemoteAddr()

String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();